Mactex requires more than 9GB of space. Any alternative or plans to bring its size to something reasonable?
I recently installed MacTex and realised how huge this piece of software is respect to anything else. It makes it really hard to have a docker container with latex installed, or to embed it into a web app without huge workaround. Or just to download the installed in reasonable time without a performant connection.
It is not simple to me to understand why a markup language, that also started in the '80, should take twice as much as Windows 10 OS (4.20 GB).

Why is has become so big over time?

Is there any plan to reduce it in size?

How do I recommend latex to students who have no access to latest hardware and connection?



Install texlive directly and choose a more minimal installation scheme. You will probalby have to readjust editors for Mac manually though as this does not setup the texbin stuff.

Installing a complete texlive (mactex) is convenient as you don't have to worry about which packages you need. If you have additional constrains, like internet connection or storage space, you can just install what you need.

a 1980's tex distribution didn't include font support for Chinese (for example) supporting languages costs space for fonts. My texlive2024 texmf-dist directory is 8.1G of which 3.9G is texmf-dist/doc and 3.0G is texmf-dist/fonts  so essentially all the space is documentation and fonts. If you don't need documentation and don't need CJK fonts you can drastically reduce the size even if you install every latex package (texmf-dist/tex is 605M with a full texlive install)
